# How do I archive a Time Machine drive to disk image?

Tags: backup, time-machine, disk-utility, time-capsule, sparsebundle

Is it possible to archive a Time Machine backup drive? I’m aiming to trash some older physical media and would like to migrate the contents to a larger drive without all the overhead that Time Machine comes with. Near as I can tell, this is not possible due to the way Apple structures the Time Machine backup. This is a 750GB drive with just over 500GB in use. A few notes:

1. I’ll never be backing up to this drive again
2. I’ll never need to restore from this drive the typical way you’d restore from Time Machines. I’ll be manually poking around the folder structure for files if needed.
3. Ideally I’d like this archive to be a single file that would be easily portable and something that could be mounted like a DMG
4. It seems that .sparsebundle files would be an ideal way to archive these. It is what Time Capsule does but I can't figure out how to create them in Disk Utility or the terminal
5. I have a Time Capsule at my disposal as well as a PC and linux machines at my disposal. My main macOS computer is running 10.15.4 but I have access to older versions of macOS if any of these help make this happen